# Converting laravel function to ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have function where i can save new specification to my database while I'm creating products, It is working just fine but it has one issue:

> It has to refresh my page, while i filled my product data some of
>   them will be lost during this refresh.

So I thought it would be better if I use ajax function for it, here is my codes:

`blade`

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'addnewsupspecinprodcreat')) }}

{{ Form::label('specification_id', 'Parent Specification') }}
<select class="form-control" name="specification_id">
@foreach($specifications as $specification)
  <option value="{{ $specification->id }}">{{ $specification->title }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>

{{ Form::label('title', 'Name') }}
{{ Form::text('title', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}

{{ Form::label('status_id', 'Include filters?') }}
<select class="form-control" name="status_id">
@foreach($statuses as $status)
  <option value="{{ $status->id }}">{{ $status->title }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

`controller`

```
public function addnewsupspecinprodcreat(Request $req)
{
        Subspecification::create([
            'title' => $req->title,
            'specification_id' => $req->specification_id,
            'status_id' => $req->status_id,
        ]);
      Session::flash('success', 'Your Sub-specification saved successfully.');
      return redirect()->back();
}
```

`route`

```
Route::post('/addnewsupspecinprodcreat', 'ProductController@addnewsupspecinprodcreat')->name('addnewsupspecinprodcreat');
```

## Question

What should I change to convert my function to Ajax?

## UPDATE

I changed my data like:

`blade form`

```
{{Form::open()}}

{{ Form::label('spac_id', 'Parent Specification') }}
<select class="form-control" id="spac_id" name="spac_id">
  @foreach($specifications as $specification)
    <option value="{{ $specification->id }}">{{ $specification->title }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>

{{ Form::label('spectitle', 'Name') }}
{{ Form::text('spectitle', null, array('id' => 'spectitle', 'class' => 'form-control')) }}

{{ Form::label('stat_id', 'Include filters?') }}
<select class="form-control" id="stat_id" name="stat_id">
  @foreach($statuses as $status)
    <option value="{{ $status->id }}">{{ $status->title }}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>

<button type="submit" id="modalsave" class="modalsave btn btn-primary">Save</button>

{{Form::close()}}
```

added `script`

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready( function() {
    $("#modalsave").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });

      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('admin/addnewsupspecinprodcreat') }}",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          title: $("#spectitle").val(),
          specification_id: $("i#spac_id").val(),
          status_id: $("#stat_id").val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
      });
  });
});
</script>
```

changed `function` to:

```
public function addnewsupspecinprodcreat(Request $req)
    {
      $add = Subspecification::create([
          'title' => $req->spectitle,
          'specification_id' => $req->spac_id,
          'status_id' => $req->stat_id,
      ]);

      if($add){
        Session::flash('success', 'Your Sub-specification saved successfully.');
      }else{
        Session::flash('danger', 'Your Sub-specification saved successfully.');
      }
    }
```

Issue:

I'm getting `419` error on my Ajax which is related to my `token` code but interesting part is that I have

```
$.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
});
```

in my script, really not sure why i get `419` error. any idea?

`my error`

```
Error: 
{…}
​
abort: function abort()
​
always: function always()
​
complete: function add()
​
done: function add()
​
error: function add()
​
fail: function add()
​
getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()
​
getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()
​
overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()
​
pipe: function then()
​
progress: function add()
​
promise: function promise()
​
readyState: 4
​
responseJSON: Object { exception: "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\HttpException", file: "C:\\laragon\\www\\xxxxx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php", line: 203, … }
​
responseText: "{\n    \"message\": \"\",\n    \"exception\": \"Symfony\\\\Component\\\\HttpKernel\\\\Exception\\\\HttpException\",\n    \"file\": \"C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\xxxxxx\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler.php\",\n    \"line\": 203,\n    \"trace\": [\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\xxxxxx\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler.php\",\n            \"line\": 175,\n            \"function\": \"prepareException\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\xxxxxx\\\\app\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler.php\",\n            \"line\": 51,\n            \"function\": \"render\",\n            \"class\": \"Illuminate\\\\Foundation\\\\Exceptions\\\\Handler\",\n            \"type\": \"->\"\n        },\n        {\n            \"file\": \"C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\xxxxxx\\\\vendor\\\\laravel\\\\framework\\\\src\\\\Illuminate\\\\Routing\\\\Pipeline.php\",\n            \"line\": 83,\n            \"functi…"
​
setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()
​
state: function state()
​
status: 419
​
statusCode: function statusCode()
​
statusText: "unknown status"
​
success: function add()
​
then: function then()
​
__proto__: Object { … }
```

## UPDATE 2

I have changed my `script` to code below:

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready( function() {
    $("#modalsave").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "{{ url('admin/addnewsupspecinprodcreat') }}",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        _token: $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        title: $('input[name=spectitle]').val(),
        specification_id: $('input[name=spac_id]').val(),
        status_id: $('input[name=stat_id]').val(),
      },
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
          console.log('Error:', data);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Now I'm getting error `500` in my network, here is `response` of it:

> message   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'title' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `subspecifications` (`title`,
>   `specification_id`, `status_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (,
>   , , 2018-03-22 15:48:21, 2018-03-22 15:48:21))

Comment: Can you explain more about the refresh, why the refresh is necessary, and how that is a problem for you?

Comment: @Daniel refreshing is not necessary for me that's why i try to avoid it by using ajax. and why i want to use ajax? is because to get added `specification` at the time is added in my select box.

Comment: So you aren't wanting to refresh because you lose the data you entered in the form fields?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

my final script is:

```
<script>
  $( document ).ready( function() {
    $("#modalsave").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "{{ url('admin/addnewsupspecinprodcreat') }}",
      data: {
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        'spectitle': $('input[name=spectitle]').val(),
        'spac_id': $('#spac_id').val(),
        'stat_id': $('#stat_id').val(),
      },
      success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      },
      error: function (data) {
          console.log('Error:', data);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

PS: You can find latest `function` and `form` in my question `update`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

From your controller you can redirect back with input data posted with previous request

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

Comment: the issue is i have some fields like multiple select, no matter we say in controller they will lose in page refresh, sometimes even my textarea's will wipe clean.

Comment: can you paste your code for multiselect and textarea?